# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts when I publish ABP to Ubuntu with Docker

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-boilerplate

I've tried to publish My Asp Boilerplate project to Ubuntu using Docker , but I got a problem. Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

```
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
**crit:** Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[6]
      Application startup exception
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.<ConnectAsync>d__56.MoveNext() in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ServerSession.cs:line 239
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.<CreateSessionAsync>d__77.MoveNext() in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 365
```

Here's my
connection,

```
 {
      "ConnectionStrings": {
        "Default": "Server=128.199.250.219; Database=CityInfoDb; User Id=****; Password=******;"
      },
      "App": {
        "WebSiteRootAddress": "http://localhost:9903/"
      }
    }
```

My Docker file ,
[image: dockerfile]

Mysql ,
[image: mysql]

Maybe my dockerfile incorrect , Please help me I'm frustated.

Comment: up, pelase help :(

Comment: Post the exception stacktrace not the screenshots. Read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: alright , that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string seems to be incorrect, please find below the example.

```
{

"ConnectionStrings": {
"Default": "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=1234;database=mysqldemodb"
},
 ...
}
```

You can refer [EF Core MySql Integration](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/EF-Core-MySql-Integration).

Comment: Sure, let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: same problem , doesn't change . do you have any idea? @vivek nuna

Comment: Check MQSql running or not

Comment: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/32407979/37580092-89928110-2b74-11e8-8cac-baaef70e81ff.PNG 

@vivek nuna